# How can I implement a multiple select for filtering in Kendo Grid ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

I'm developing an application with **Kendo Controls of 2014** (***I don't have access to the newest one 2017 or 2018***). In this project, I have several columns of the Foreign Key type like this one:

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.StatusID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["status"], "ID", "Name").HeaderTemplate("Status")
```

In order to create the grid I followed the basic example:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/foreignkeycolumn

For the basic implementation, it looks and works as expected the users can select from a variety of Status or Users in the **filtering** and **editing** options.

However, I would like to be able to select more than one at once. I tried to migrate this example, which is for **Kendo for jQuery**:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/filtering/multiselect-used-for-column-filtering.html

Where they implemented a **Multi Select**.

[image: multiselect]

That should be enough to satisfy my needs. I tried to migrate to the ASP MVC and now, it looks like this:

```
@model object

@(
 Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m)
    .BindTo((MultiSelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
)
```

Basically, I replaced the Drop Down list into a Multi Select, but nothing changed my filtering is still displaying the normal Drop Down, there is no Multi Select:

[image: dropdownlist]

Maybe I should do more changes, but I don't know what else I should change; I would like to know if someone has ever experienced this before and how they handled it, I have tried multiple examples and codes, but my template newer changes, it's always the Drop Down List. Another interesting example, but it's in jQuery too, I haven't been able to find an implementation in ASP MVC:

http://jsfiddle.net/victordscott/5kbfY/

Besides, I'm aware that what I would like to achieve is available since 2015 Q1:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-multi-checkboxes

Unfortunately, I don't have access to any newer version as I explained before. Thanks in advance for any idea.

Comment: So you are unable to update the controls & you're not using JavaScript/jQuery?.. [Pros and cons using MVC wrappers vs HTML/JS widgets](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/kendo-ui-vs-mvc-wrappers#list-of-pros-and-cons). For me (after working with both over the last 2 years), MVC wrappers feel very restrictive and you should really consider Client-side implementation, _especially_ when you're attempting to apply customization to the standard controls.

Comment: Hi @Sandman I understand your point and I prefer jQuery, but my client and team is fully working in ASP, that's why I'm a bit restricted of ASP MVC and not jQuery. Also, I should rewrite a lot of code and it won't be standard of one part in ASP and only one section in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it's available in this older version, but you could give it a try with use of "EditorTemplate"

code for EditorTemplate: (place in folder "EditorTemplates", name it f.e: "myeditortemplate.cshtml")

```
@model object    

@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
          .Name("optional")
          .AutoClose(false)
          .Placeholder("Select attendees...")
          .BindTo(new List<string>() {
              "value1",
              "value2",        
          })
    )
```

or for remote-datasource:

```
@model object    

@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
          .Name("optional")
          .AutoClose(false)
          .Placeholder("Select attendees...")
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("ReadAction", "MyController");
              });
          })
    )
```

then in the grid-definition:

```
...
..
   column.Bound(c => c.optional).EditorTemplateName("myeditortemplate");
..
..
```

cheers

Comment: Hi, no, it doesn't work, I tried it. Thanks for your time :).